# Check that that the sequence $(-1)^{n}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )$ converge or not.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Please check my proof and point the flaw in the proof :)
$(-1)^{n}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )< \epsilon $

because n is even the sequence will be

$1\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )$

$\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )< \epsilon $

$\frac{n-1}{n}< \epsilon $

$n-1< \epsilon n$

since inequality hold Limit exist and convergence to some number.

we conclude for $|\frac{n-1}{n}|< \epsilon $

If n is odd

$(-1)^{2n+1} = -1$

$ -1\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )< \epsilon $

$ -1+\frac{1}{n}< \epsilon $

$ \frac{-n+1}{n}< \epsilon $

because the inequality hold limit exist at some number can converge to the same

then $\frac{-n+1}{n}< \epsilon $

But $|\frac{-n+1}{n}\neq |\frac{n-1}{n}|$

and limit is unique.

We conclude no limit exist for this sequence;divergent

Comment: Observe that the sequence is made of two subsequences $(1-1/n)$ and $-(1-1/n)$ for even and odd $n$, which clearly converge to limits $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the inequality $n-1<\epsilon n$ hold?

For example, what if $\epsilon = 0.001$ and $n=1000$? The inequality then becomes $999 < 1$, something you will probably agree is not true. In fact, if $\epsilon \leq \frac12$, then the inequality
$$n-1<\epsilon n$$

will **only hold for $n=1$**, since for $n\geq 2$, you have $$\epsilon n < \frac 12 n =n-\frac 12n  \leq n-\frac 12 \cdot 2 = n-1$$

i.e. the oposite of your inequality.

---

What you need to show is not that $1-\frac 1n$ is small (it is **not**), but that $1-\frac 1n$ is **close to $1$**. In other words, you have to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N$ such that if $n>N$, then the distance between $1$ and $1-\frac1n$ is smaller than $\epsilon$ (I'll leave it to you to fully formalize this statement).

That, along with showing that $-(1-\frac1n)$ is close to $-1$, is enough to see that the sequence has two convergence points and thus cannot converge.

Answer (score -1):

Let  $a_n:=(-1)^{n}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )$

Then $a_{2n}=\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right ) \to 1$ and $a_{2n-1}=\left ( -1+\frac{1}{n} \right )\to -1$

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question OP is asking. He isn't asking whether the sequence converges, he is asking whether his proof is correct.